# How to make GET request to API continuously?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am making GET request to my database and the data is coming in and showing up, but the moment the data gets updated on my database it does not get updated on the component which uses that data.

**Edit**
Based on the comments I need to make GET request continuously so I updated the question.

**useEffect() to set the data to state**

```
// Data for each of the tags
const [tag1, setTag1] = useState();
const [tag2, setTag2] = useState();
const [tag3, setTag3] = useState();

useEffect(() => {
    axios
        .get(URL)
        .then(res => {
            const data = res.data;
            // Passing in the setter method
            setTagDetails(data, setTag1, setTag2, setTag3);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        });
}, []);
```

**setTagDetails() where the data coming in is split into different states to be used in the component:**

```
// Splitting the data by each corresponding tag and adding them to their respective state
export const setTagDetails = (data, setTag1, setTag2, setTag3) => {
    const arr1 = [];
    const arr2 = [];
    const arr3 = [];
    try {
        data &&
            data.forEach(d => {
                // Entries into the database which do not have any tag information
                // have a size of 5 and those with all the details have a size of 6
                const sizeOfObject = Object.keys(d).length;
                // Only need database items with all the details
                if (sizeOfObject > 5) {
                    // Split the data for the tags into their respective name
                    const name = d["tags"]["L"][0]["M"]["name"]["S"];
                    // Will be used to set individual datasets for each tag
                    if (name === "Tag1") {
                        cleanTag(d, arr1);
                    }
                    if (name === "Tag2") {
                        cleanTag(d, arr2);
                    }
                    if (name === "Tag3") {
                        cleanTag(d, arr3);
                    }
                }
            });
        setTag1(arr1);
        setTag2(arr2);
        setTag3(arr3);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
};
```

Comment: that's the behavior of restful services, to capture latest transactions in the backend its needed to send a http request per demand to get an updated response.

Comment: I see so I would have to make a GET request over say every 1-2 seconds to update the data?

Comment: You may consider working with SSE (server sent events) to notify the client on server updates https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events

Comment: I'll have a look at it. My data is coming from sensors so I need the data to be updated whenever new data is sent to the database.

Comment: yeah there are a lot of options, Server sent events, websockets long polling to load new content in realtime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want to execute a function every x amount of time, we use the [setInterval method](https://upmostly.com/tutorials/setinterval-in-react-components-using-hooks). It will call the passed in function (as the first argument) every x milliseconds (where x is the second argument, in the case below, 1000 ms, or 1 second).

```
useEffect(() => {
const interval = setInterval(() => {
   axios
    .get(URL)
    .then(res => {
        const data = res.data;
        // Passing in the setter method
        setTagDetails(data, setTag1, setTag2, setTag3);
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
    });
  }, 1000);
  return () => clearInterval(interval);
}, []);
```

Please note, it is best practice to be mindful of user's internet connections, in the case of a slow mobile network or a bandwidth limited ISP policy. There is also a danger of running the requests so close together that we introduce a race condition. Lastly, you **MUST** clear the interval, otherwise you will significantly hamper the performance of your app.

Comment: If I am passing in the items from ```setTag``` to child components would I have to clean them up there as well or just in the useEffect()?

Comment: Not sure I understand your question... clean the interval up?

Comment: Sorry yes I meant clean the interval. Would I only have to do it just in the useEffect()?

Comment: Yeah since the interval is scoped to the useEffect hook.

Comment: i will not recommend this approach, this will overwhelm your api server you will notice this when you scale the number of users in your application.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend it either, but it is what he asked to do. I think websockets would be a much more practical option, as you suggested.